# XSLT query without umlauts

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, profile

I have in xslt code first and last name selects

```
            <xsl:value-of select="@firstname" />
            <xsl:text xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" ddwrt:whitespace-preserve="yes" xml:space="preserve"> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@lastname" />
```

I used xslt concat method which is pointing above to Sharepoint people user profile page link. This works well.

Problem is that some name are with umlauts ex. Tiina Tähtvere, but profile pages pointing to domain name in the end ex. domain/Tiina.Tahtvere without umlauts answer. Ofcourse user is not found then.

Is possible to make domain name without umalauts in xslt code and how? Thanks for any answers. Hopefully this was clear explenation.

I use XSLT 1.0 and Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: So are you wanting the umlauts removed from the name? Your examples seem to contradict each other in that you say there are no umlauts in the domain and that causes an error but you then ask how to remove the umlauts. Do you have the input XML and an example of the output you want?

Comment: Sorry, for my misunderstood explenation. Yes, I want umlauts removed from the name, because in domain haven't any umlauts. I have query with my variables <xsl:element name="a"> <xsl:attribute name="href"> <xsl:value-of select="concat('http://',$url_HTTP_HOST ,'/', $wildcard, '/', $UPurl, $domain, '\' ,@firstname, '.' ,@lastname)" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> </xsl:attribute> </xsl:element> `. Output is ex. http://myhost/mywildcard/person.aspx/domain\tiina.tähtvere, but i want http://myhost/mywildcard/person.aspx/domain\tiina.tahtvere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath/Functions/translate) function to convert your umlauts to standard characters. So you can just update your example to the below:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(@lastname,'&#xE4;','a')"/>
```

I used the character encoding of that character in the translate because my process was giving an error about the specific character encoding but either should work.

Also, if you have additional characters you would just add them to the translate function as well.